# db2batch using stored procedures with parameter files

Tags: db2

I'm trying to find examples of how to use db2batch with stored procedure calls and parameter files.

I have a stored procedure I'd like to call a number of times and provide the parameters from a file however I'm struggling to find documentation that shows how this might be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on using parameter files is certainly not very good.  However you can indeed call a stored procedure** using `db2batch`.

Here is an example of the command line:

```
db2batch -d yourdb -iso cs -f stmts.sql -m stmts.data
```

The SQL file (`stmts.sql`) that calls the procedure would look something like this:

```
--#BGBLK 5
call my.storedproc(?, ?);
--#EOBLK
```

The number after the `--#BGBLK` instructs `db2batch` to execute the statement(s) in the block 5 times.

Your parameter file (`stmts.data`) would look like this (this example is for a stored procedure where the first argument to the stored proc is an `INT` and the second argument is a `VARCHAR(15)`, and both are `IN` parameters):

```
1 'First'
2 'Second'
3 'Third'
4 'Fourth'
5 'Fifth'
6 'Sixth'
7 'Seventh'
8 'Eighth'
9 'Ninth'
10 'Tenth'
```

There are 10 pairs of parameters in this file, but since the `--#BGBLK` identifier specified a repeat count of only 5, db2batch will read only the first 5 lines in the parameter file. If you specify a repeat count that is larger than the number of lines in the parameter file you'll get errors for the repetitions that don't have corresponding values from the parameter file.

**Note: `db2batch` will work on procedures that have `IN` parameters, and will even handle stored procedures that return result set(s), but I am not aware of a way to get it to work with stored procedures that have `OUT` parameters.

Comment: Thansk Ian that's very helpful, shame about the out parameters as we use those in every stored procedure we have :(

Comment: I've had a crack at the OUT parameters and it appears as long as the type is the same it works ok for me

Comment: @sapatos Can you clarify "the type is the same"?  Is that for `INOUT` parameters or for purely `OUT` parameters?

Comment: This was for OUT only parameters, also clarified with IBM and their solution was also to provide dummy values to the OUT parameters. 'type is the same' meaning '' passed to char/varchar, 0 passed to INT for example